# Mysql multiple join query record issue

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my query ,

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    CONCAT(u.FirstName, ' ', u.LastName) as customer, 
    (
        (
            CASE WHEN pmt.TotalCreditedAmt IS NOT NULL THEN pmt.TotalCreditedAmt ELSE 0 END
        ) - (
            CASE WHEN trns.TotalDeductAmt IS NOT NULL THEN trns.TotalDeductAmt ELSE 0 END
        )
    ) as closing_balance 
FROM 
    (`Users` as u) 
    JOIN `UserAddresses` as uaddresses ON `u`.`Id` = `uaddresses`.`UserId` 
    AND (
        uaddresses.PreferredPickUpAddress = "Yes"
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            sum(CreditedAmount) AS TotalCreditedAmt, 
            UserId 
        FROM 
            Payment 
        where 
            PaymentSucc = "Yes" 
                    GROUP BY 
            UserId
    ) as pmt ON `pmt`.`UserId` = `u`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            sum(Amount) AS TotalDeductAmt, 
            UserId 
        FROM 
            Transaction 

        GROUP BY 
            UserId
    ) as trns ON `trns`.`UserId` = `u`.`id` 
WHERE 
    `u`.`UserType` = 'User' 
    AND `uaddresses`.`PincodeId` IN ('10369', '10372', '10309') 
ORDER BY 
    `u`.`id` desc
```

From above query from user address table condition my users table records are 80

from that 80 records in payment table records are 31 and in transaction table entry are 9 with group by query in this tables

from both the tables(payment & transaction) unique users are 34 means some user are in payment and some users are in transaction in result there are total distinct user are 34 from 80 users.

my required result is 34 users but it gives me 80 users

can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Join instead of Left join should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your vlaueable reply, but I need users from payment and transaction both the tables

in join of useraddress it is 80 user it is fine
in join of payment table it will be 31 users
in join of transaction table it will be 9 users

I want distinct users from payment and transaction it is 34.
please can you help me to find this result